# sorting a grouped list based on column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have created a list group by year as below. i need to sort the blow with 2016 year part on the top( as shown in the second image). i can do that by clicking the year field and select "Z to A" but as soon as i refresh or browse away from the page and come back to the site it goes away. is there any chance i can set it up by default ?

how it is 
[image]

how i wanted it

[image]

i have edited the view
[image]

Comment: Did you try editing the view and select sorting on the year column in descending order?

Comment: yes and i have updated the question with a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select sort order while grouping on particular column. Make sure the view group by settings is as per below

[image]

Comment: it's already sorted as described in the last screen shot but its still not workind

Comment: The screen shot in my comment is from Group By settings. Go to Modify View -> Expand Group By and you will see the setting there.

Comment: oh yes, i was looking under sort by. its showing as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select "show groups in descending order" in GroupBy settings.

What you are doing selecting in Sort By Settings.

Above is tried and tested, it is working.